# I'm curious why 'first-of-type' is doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

> I expect only green div have padding. but it looks every div have padding.
>   I'm curious why 'first-of-type' is doesn't work.
>   and i need the solution.
>   please give me any advice, thank you

```css
.test {background-color:red; border:1px solid #000; width:500px;height:500px;}
.test div {background-color:green;width:300px;height:300px; border:1px solid #000;}
.test div div {background-color:pink;width:300px;height:250px; border:1px solid #000;}
.test div div div {background-color:yellow;width:300px;height:200px; border:1px solid #000;}
.test div:first-of-type {padding:30px;}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.test div` is a [**descendant selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), and thus targets **any** `<div>` descendant of `.test`, not just *direct* descendants. It also includes grandchildren and great-grandchildren.

In your example, **all** of your descendant elements would be green, though this isn't immediately obvious due to the fact that you are overriding this rule with increased [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/):

[image]

In addition to this, [**`:first-of-type`**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/) targets the first element of that type within its container. Each `<div>` is wrapped within another `<div>`, and because each one has no siblings, it is automatically the **first** child. That is why each of your child elements not only meets the `.test div` criteria, but also the `.test div:first-of-type` criteria.

If you want only the direct descendant (the green `<div>`) to have padding, you should make use of the [**direct child combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) (`>`) as `.test > div:first-of-type`:

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.test div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test div div {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test div div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test > div:first-of-type {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A space between selectors [indicates that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) the first is an *ancestor* of the second. Use the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) instead, with `>`:

```css
.test {background-color:red; border:1px solid #000; width:500px;height:500px;}
.test > div {background-color:green;width:300px;height:300px; border:1px solid #000;}
.test > div > div {background-color:pink;width:300px;height:250px; border:1px solid #000;}
.test > div > div > div {background-color:yellow;width:300px;height:200px; border:1px solid #000;}
.test > div:first-of-type {padding:30px;}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(note that because `.test` only has one child, the `first-of-type` doesn't make any difference for this HTML - that one child would be selected regardless with `.test > div`)

Comment: we only need `>` for the last selector. for the others you will override the previous styles.